# Best way to get the MAC of eth0?

Tags: linux, mac, ethernet, awk, net

Is there a more efficient way to retrieve the MAC address of a NIC in Linux?

This works:

```
ip link show dev eth0 | awk ' /link\/ether/ { print $2 }'
```

but can it be found via something like:

```
cat /sys/net/something
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's at `/sys/class/net/eth0/address` (or more precisely `/sys/devices/pciXXXX:XX/XXXX/net/eth0/address` where the XXX is your PCI bus ID, but this varies between systems).

(Incidentally, I found this with `find /sys -name eth0` and looking at the files in the directories identified.)

Answer (score 4):

It's also available via `ifconfig`:

```
kce@thinkpad:~$ /sbin/ifconfig eth0 |grep HWaddr
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:37:cc:ce:cc
```

Or if you want just the MAC address:

```
kce@thinkpad:~$ /sbin/ifconfig eth0 |awk '/HWaddr/{print $5}'
00:1e:37:cc:ce:cc
```

Comment: Well, you still have to awk or cut it. Because the mac is at the end of line.

Answer (score 3):

if you can install `moreutils` package, there is a `ifdata` tool. Description says:

> ifdata: get network interface info without parsing ifconfig output

Here's an example:

```
me@box:~$ ifdata -ph eth0
00:21:86:61:35:44
```